# How to define styles for features in JSON file

Tags: openlayers, style, json

Styles for rendering features in OpenLayers 3 are defined as:

```
new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Circle({
    radius: 6,
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'white',
      width: 2
    }),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'green'
    })
  })
})
```

I would like to define my styles in JSON file, not in code. Is there any way how to load styles from JSON? I could easily load attributes like `"color" : "green"`, but I cannot load something like `new ol.style.Fill`...

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, OL3 does not provide that. You have to define your own json structure and write a function to read that json and apply it to the layer.

[GeoExt 3](https://geoext.github.io/geoext3/) provides a very nice `getSerializedLayers` that encodes the data and the style in one json. To print a OL3 vector layer with [MapFish](http://mapfish.github.io/mapfish-print-doc/index.html), you need to pass the features and the style to MapFish. With GeoExt 3, you do:

```
var util = GeoExt.data.MapfishPrintProvider;
var serializedLayers = util.getSerializedLayers(
    olMap,
    function (layer) {
        return (layer.get('title') == 'Detail');
    }
);
```

The resulting json looks like this (without the features):

```
{
    geoJson: {
        features: [ (...) ],
        type: "FeatureCollection"
    },
    type: "geojson",
    style: {
        version: 2,
        "[dominio = 'PLANTA ORDENAMENTO']": {
            symbolizers: [
                {
                    type: "polygon",
                    fillColor: "#ff9900",
                    fillOpacity: 0.4,
                    strokeColor: "#ff9900",
                    strokeOpacity: 1,
                    strokeWidth: 2 // , strokeDashstyle: "dot"
                }
            ]
        },
        "[dominio = 'LOTEAMENTO']": {
            symbolizers: [
                {
                    type: "polygon",
                    fillColor: "#cc00cc",
                    fillOpacity: 0.4,
                    strokeColor: "#cc00cc",
                    strokeOpacity: 1,
                    strokeWidth: 2 // , strokeDashstyle: "dot"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This is an example of the MapFish style syntax (including conditional styling).

For you application, you can use the [MapFish](http://mapfish.github.io/mapfish-print-doc/styles.html) style syntax, for example, and write the inverse of the GeoExt 3 `getSerializedLayers` function. It is just a suggestion for your problem, not an really a answer.

Comment: Thanks! I meanwhile wrote some own simple parser, but it is a great idea to use already existing style syntax.

Comment: @jgrocha do we need to import any modules before being able to use that method? I'm getting error "Couldn't find a suitable serializer for source. Did you require() an appropriate serializer class?" from the ext-all-rtl-debug.js utilitary upon using it.

Comment: @user25976 What type of layer are you trying to serialize? There are serializers for a few kind of layers, but not for all types.

Comment: @jgrocha VectorTile and OSM base map

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/pagameba/671d63f7ee95e4ebe44b

This code is supposed to be able to create OL3 Style object(s) from object literals.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the closest you can get -natively- to persisting style info, whether in a database, or config file, is to store the options property for the Style as a JSON string.

For example, myStyle.json file might look like this:

```
{"LONG_RANGE_RADAR": {
"crit":{
    "fill":{"color":"rgba(255,255,255,0.4)"},
    "stroke":{"color":"#3399CC","width":1.25} 
},
"warn":{
    "fill":{"color":"rgba(255,255,255,0.4)"},
    "stroke":{"color":"#3399CC","width":1.25} 
}}
```

This will get you half way to completely persisting an entire openlayers Style object.