# Issues printing OSM basemap using MapFishPrint 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geoext, mapfish

I'm trying to get the GeoExt MapFishPrintProvider function mentioned in this other [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/218363/how-to-define-styles-for-features-in-json-file/222623#222623) to work. However, the debug tools are writing this message to the console:

```
"Couldn't find a suitable serializer for source. Did you require() an appropriate serializer class?"
```

The page loads to show blank page with error message:

```
"Error while processing request: java.lang.NullPointerException".
```

UPDATE: I have since realized that the two errors are related to each layer respectively. There doesn't seem to be a serializer for vector tiles, so I've decided to go with a wms layer instead, which now prints fine. The osm layer is causing the java.lang.NullPointerException, which I discovered for two reasons: 1) the mapfish print examples using osm layers give the same error, and 2) removing the osm layer results in a successful print. This question is focused on the second issue, which seems less difficult to work around.

I attempted to load the modules in this way:

```
Ext.define('SIG.view.main.Main', {
   extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
   requires: [
     'Ext.plugin.Viewport',
     'Ext.window.MessageBox',
     'SIG.view.main.MainController',
     'SIG.view.main.MainModel',
     'SIG.view.main.List',
     'SIG.view.main.Map',
     'GeoExt.data.serializer.Base',
     'GeoExt.data.serializer.ImageWMS',
     'GeoExt.data.serializer.TileWMS',
     'GeoExt.data.serializer.Vector',
     'GeoExt.data.serializer.WMTS',
     'GeoExt.data.serializer.XYZ'
   ],
   controller: 'main',
   viewModel: 'main',
   layout: 'border',
   items: [
         mapComponent,
         layerTreePanel
   ]
});
```

The map and map component were created in this way.

```
window.my_map = new ol.Map({
  controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([new ol.control.ScaleLine]),
  target: 'map',
  view: view,
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Group({title: 'Fond de plans', layers: [osm_basemap], name: 'Fond de plans'}),
    new ol.layer.Group({title: 'Réseau Secosud', layers: [coupureaerien_layer], name: 'Réseau Secosud'}),
    extentLayer
  ],
  //overlays: [overlay],
});

var mapComponent = Ext.create('GeoExt.component.Map', {
  map: window.my_map,
  controller: 'main-map',
  listeners: {
    render: function(){
      //console.log('Map rendered');
      Ext.create('GeoExt.data.MapfishPrintProvider', {
          url: 'http://ourserver:8081/print/' +
                  'print/geoext/capabilities.json',
          listeners: {
              ready: onPrintProviderReady
          }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

These are the functions that employ the GeoExt3 tool getSerializedLayers, that I am assuming is causing the error.

```
var unHttpsLayers = function(layers) {
    var changed = [];
    Ext.each(layers, function(layer) {
        var clone = Ext.clone(layer);
        if (clone.baseURL && (/^https:/i).test(clone.baseURL)) {
            clone.baseURL = clone.baseURL.replace('https', 'http');
        }
        changed.push(clone);
    });
    return changed;
};

var onPrintProviderReady = function(provider) {
    // this is the assumption: take the first layout and render an
    // appropriate extent on the map
    var capabilities = provider.capabilityRec;
    var layout = capabilities.layouts().getAt(0);
    var attr = layout.attributes().getAt(0);
    var clientInfo = attr.get('clientInfo');
    var render = GeoExt.data.MapfishPrintProvider.renderPrintExtent;
    console.log(mapComponent);
    render(mapComponent, extentLayer, clientInfo);
    mapComponent.getView().on('propertychange', function() {
        extentLayer.getSource().clear();
        render(mapComponent, extentLayer, clientInfo);
    });
    var printButton = document.getElementById('print_button-btnInnerEl');
    printButton.addEventListener("click", (function() {
      console.log('got here');
      var spec = {
          layout: layout.get('name'),
          attributes: {}
      };
      console.log(spec);
      var firstFeature = extentLayer.getSource().getFeatures()[0];
      var bbox = firstFeature.getGeometry().getExtent();
      var util = GeoExt.data.MapfishPrintProvider;
      var mapView = mapComponent.getView();
      var serializedLayers = util.getSerializedLayers(
          mapComponent,
          function(layer) {
              // do not print the extent layer
              var isExtentLayer = (extentLayer === layer);
              return !isExtentLayer;
          }
      );
      console.log(serializedLayers);
      serializedLayers = unHttpsLayers(serializedLayers);
      serializedLayers.reverse();
      console.log(serializedLayers);
      spec.attributes[attr.get('name')] = {
          bbox: bbox,
          dpi: clientInfo.dpiSuggestions[0],
          layers: serializedLayers,
          projection: mapView.getProjection().getCode(),
          rotation: mapView.getRotation()
      };
      Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
          standardSubmit: true,
          url: 'http://ourserver:8081/print/' +
              'print/geoext/buildreport.pdf',
          method: 'POST',
          items: [
              {
                  xtype: 'textfield',
                  name: 'spec',
                  value: Ext.encode(spec)
              }
          ]
      }).submit();
    }));
};
```

The config.yaml file that is at the root of the print-app module directory in the servlet.

```
throwErrorOnExtraParameters: true



templates:

  A4 portrait: !template

    reportTemplate: simpleReport.jrxml

    attributes:

      map: !map

        maxDpi: 400

        width: 780

        height: 330

    processors:

    - !reportBuilder # compile all reports in current directory

      directory: '.'

    - !createMap {}
```

Printing the specs to console, I get the following. Only thing I am currently looking into is the fact that my base url has been parsed to include "/{z}/{x}/{y}/ "whereas many examples seem to end with "http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/":

```
{"layout":"A4 portrait",
    "attributes":
        {"map":
            {"bbox":[-16646158.733074246,-2014058.743123461,-16557461.205452127,-1976532.8660525647],
             "dpi":72,
             "layers":[
             {"baseURL":"http://ourserver:8081/geoserver/wms?",
              "customParams": {"LAYERS":"tahiti:elec_edt_appareil_coupure_aerien_hta",
                               "FORMAT":"image/png",
                               "TILED":true},
                               "layers":["tahiti:elec_edt_appareil_coupure_aerien_hta"],
                               "opacity":1,
                               "styles":[""],
                               "type":"WMS"},
              {"baseURL":"http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
              "opacity":1,
              "imageExtension":"png",
              "resolutions":[156543.03392804097,78271.51696402048,39135.75848201024,19567.87924100512,9783.93962050256,4891.96981025128,2445.98490512564,1222.99245256282,611.49622628141,305.748113140705,152.8740565703525,76.43702828517625,38.21851414258813,19.109257071294063,9.554628535647032,4.777314267823516,2.388657133911758,1.194328566955879,0.5971642834779395,0.29858214173896974],
              "tileSize":[256,256],
              "type":"OSM"}],
              "projection":"EPSG:3857",
              "rotation":0}
          }
}
```

Comment: Question would be much more 'user friendly' without those blank lines within code.

Comment: @TomazicM okay, thanks, noted.